# Running SQL Server 2008 on a dedicated server

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server, hosting, dedicated-server

What do I need to know about running SQL Server 2008 on a dedicated server as far as licensing goes?  What would my cheapest option be?  Also, for a fairly small web application, would shared hosting make more sense?  (These both would be through a hosting provider)
Thanks!

-Shane

Comment: If your server is on the Internet, you'll need that licence. SQL licensing is usually per physical CPU either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A full SQL license is expensive. I would recommend using shared hosting, or run MySQL.

Comment: Thanks - that's pretty much the conclusion I've come to as well.  Looks like I'm switching to MySQL!

Answer (score 1):

I beleive SQL Server Express is free to use without any licensing...it can handle databases up to 2GB i think.

Also you don't get access to the SQL Server Agent and a few other technical parts of the full version...but if you don't need them then it should work fine for small apps.

Paul

Comment: Maximum database size is increased to 10GB for sql server 2008R2 expressed http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=SQL.105).aspx